# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, facebook

I tried to make a Facebook connection, but it seems I made a mistake, and now my Facebook button crashes.

```
public class FacebookConnect extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    public String TAG;


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            nextActivity(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                                                       AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                nextActivity(currentProfile);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.facebookSignupButton);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                nextActivity(profile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        nextActivity(profile);
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void nextActivity(Profile profile){
        if (profile != null){
            Intent main = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
            main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
            startActivity(main);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how to solve it ?

This is actually the error when I clicked on, I have the same problem when I tried make a google connection too.

> 12-07 19:54:48.717 3772-3772/com.climb.eip.climb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.climb.eip.climb, PID: 3772
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.climb.eip.climb/com.climb.eip.climb.utils.FacebookConnect}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(java.lang.String[])'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(java.lang.String[])'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   com.climb.eip.climb.utils.FacebookConnect.onCreate(FacebookConnect.java:76)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

where is ?

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

in onCreate()

So add this line with your layout name in onCreate() after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: I put, the setContentView with my layout, but I have the same issue, on this line "loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");"

Comment: I added setContentView(R.layout.<your activity layout>) and the error went away.